# Определение элемента при делегировании

Tags: javascript

Подскажите, как используя делегирование научить программу "понимать" на каком элементе произошло событие?

Например, имеется родительский блок и пять кнопок в нем. Слушатель висит на родителе. Скажем, при нажатии на кнопку 3 в консоль должно быть выведено сообщение: "Вы нажали кнопку 3" и т.д.

Ключевым моментом является тот факт, что у кнопок имеется только один класс и нет уникальных id и прочих отличий. Код должен работать без привязки к содержимому названия кнопки, т.е. не учитывать содержимое в теге span

Пример разметки:

```html
<div class="map">

  <button class="map__pin">
    <span class="map__btn-text">Кнопка 1</span>
  </button>
  <button class="map__pin">
      <span class="map__btn-text">Кнопка 2</span>
  </button>
  <button class="map__pin">
      <span class="map__btn-text">Кнопка 3</span>
  </button>
  <button class="map__pin">
      <span class="map__btn-text">Кнопка 4</span>
  </button>
  <button class="map__pin">
      <span class="map__btn-text">Кнопка 5</span>
  </button>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
document.querySelector(".map").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  var children = this.querySelectorAll(".map__btn-text");
  for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
    if (event.target == children[i] || event.target == children[i].parentNode) {
      console.log("You clicked item " + (i + 1));
      break;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="map">

  <button class="map__pin">
    <span class="map__btn-text">Кнопка 1</span>
  </button>
  <button class="map__pin">
      <span class="map__btn-text">Кнопка 2</span>
  </button>
  <button class="map__pin">
      <span class="map__btn-text">Кнопка 3</span>
  </button>
  <button class="map__pin">
      <span class="map__btn-text">Кнопка 4</span>
  </button>
  <button class="map__pin">
      <span class="map__btn-text">Кнопка 5</span>
  </button>

</div>
```

Comment: Вопрос в том, как это реализовать без привязки к содержанию кнопки, то есть без  e.target.textContent ?

Comment: @russian-stan нет, вопрос не в этом.

Comment: Я уточнил свой вопрос в описании

Comment: @russian-stan В предложении "Вы нажали кнопку 3" - число "3" откуда должно взяться?

Comment: @russian-stan, Всё верно - целевой элемент находится в `target` объекта события. А там уже какие хотите свойства.

Comment: А если бы вместо названия кнопок были пробелы или одинаковая картинка?

Comment: Да, все верно, поиск элемента должен быть по его индексу.

Comment: @russian-stan Объясните, пожалуйста, в вопросе, чего Вы хотите.